# How can i play .MTS videos in elementary OS?

Tags: applications, vlc, videos

Is it a Codec issue? 
i just try with Video,VLC, with mplayer, with,i try to convert it with openshot, with avidemux, but it does not work, someone have any suggestions? 
i can play it in mac and windows with quicktime.

Comment: Could you provide some error messages, please?

Comment: Did you try SMplayer? According to Google that should be able to play it. `sudo apt-get install smplayer`. It does seem to require some graphical horsepower tho.

Comment: I honestly have difficulty to believe vlc couldn't play it. Can you post the video or it's part somewhere so I can try it? As long as it's not copyrighted of course..

Comment: Open a terminal and type `avprobe YOURFILE.mts`, and paste the output. This will provide information about the video (codecs) that will help determine the problem.

Comment: Try the Mpv media player (FFmpeg version), here is the ppa for you:  ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests

Comment: @bigbang the error that gaves me is "No URi Set" http://imgur.com/AYcBT77

Comment: @Jeroen i try it with smplayer and Mplayer, it does not work

Comment: @andrew79 is really weird
avprobe version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Apr 10 2015 23:18:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
00019.MTS: No such file or directory
# avprobe output
Thanks

Comment: @jan this is the file https://mega.nz/#!DIE0SJQB

Comment: Try to install ubuntu-restricted-extras packages. This should fix the problem.

Comment: The output from avprobe tells you it can not find the file. Run the command again, but make sure you specify the path for your file (and also note that the file name is case sensitive).

Comment: @Thrashie the link asks for encryption key (don't post it publicly here). Can you upload it to e.g. ulozto.net ?

Comment: @jan i got no problem, is a public video !Gsz3fbC-xUBu-GvuGmJ2ejGaRtYEzNNvc9rp5rHJDig

Comment: the video is here http://ulozto.net/xTTx8zBz/00066-copia-mts

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Ubuntu Restricted Extras:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Cheers!